# Can we remove the semicolon-# tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

[semicolon-#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semicolon-%23) is a tag for challenges related to the language `;#`. I suggest we remove this tag, since it is very localized and we've pretty much exhausted all non-duplicate challenges concerning this language and derivatives thereof. I predict most of the future challenges that could possibly be tagged with this tag would either be a duplicate of a previous language-implementation challenge or just a poor challenge in general.

Comment: I was questioning its existence too but I realized that it's just like all the programming language tags ([tag:python], [tag:java], [tag:jelly], etc.). I dunno where that puts it in the argument though.

Comment: @icrieverytim  At least with those languages, there are some elements to dig into. `;#` is a very one-dimensional language.

Comment: I tend to agree with removing the tag, but because I find it lacks interest, not because of the reason you say. It is true that challenges about `;#` have probably been exahusted, but is that a reason for deleting it? Tags do not exist only for the sake of future challenges; they are also useful for tagging existing challenges

Comment: @LuisMendo right, but I feel that the scope of the tag is too small (and will never increase in an appreciated way) to be useful

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Burninate it

As the author of `;#` and the original challenge, I kind of feel obligated to weigh in here. The [semicolon-#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semicolon-%23) tag doesn't really add anything to the site, and as demonstrated by my last attempt, <s>all</s> most variations of the original challenge have been done.*

I see no real point in having a language specific tag for every "Implement this language" question, otherwise we'd have a tidal wave of useless one-hit wonder tags.

`;#` had its (undeserved) moment of fame, I think it's time we got rid of the tag, as it contributes to giving new users the wrong impression about language-specific challenges.

<sub>* If you can really pull off a well written and well thought out `;#` challenge, then good for you. It doesn't mean that 99% of related challenge ideas aren't boring/already done.</sub>

Comment: This site has consistently demonstrated to me that "All ___ have been done" is never true.  (Still agree with the post, though)

Answer (score 15):

## Lets remove some other language tags too

I have noticed a large number of language based tags that are only attached to one or two questions.  Particularly a large number of tags only attached to a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question.  And if we intend to get rid of [semicolon-#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semicolon-%23)  we should get rid of some other seldom used language-based tags.

Comment: A cursory reading through of questions tagged [code-golf][tips] suggests these tags can go: [tag:sed], [tag:dc], [tag:swift] (3 questions but 2 are closed), [tag:smilebasic], [tag:f#], [tag:k], [tag:japt], [tag:burlesque], [tag:s.i.l.o.s].

Comment: [tag:go] also has a tips question, and can probably be removed.  It's on 5 total, but the other 4 are regarding the board game, not the language.

Comment: @Riker I've edited [tag:go].  Even if we do want go tag, it certainly should not be the same tag for the game and the language.  That simply makes no sense.

Comment: I completely agree. I'm in favor of keeping the tag for the game, but maybe a mod could rename it to "[go-game]" or similar.

Comment: What's the policy here?  If a tag has just a few questions, we remove it?  Do  new language tags get a trial period before we decide to remove them or not?

Comment: @NathanMerrill I think we should add a tag once we see that it is needed.  If we ask a few questions about a language we should then make a tag.

Comment: Do you mind if I turn this into a proper discussion question? i.e. which languages should be removed?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't think this really needs a full policy.  Dead tags should be removed.  It seems people for the most part want to remove language stubs.  I think this is a place we can self regulate without having much further discussion.  However go ahead, I can't stop you.

Answer (score 8):

## Get rid of it

;# produced some interesting challenges that, while they benefited from being related to the language (the ridiculousness of language itself pushed it far), could definitely have been standalone and unrelated challenges.

;# is also a valid language *only* for [kolmorgorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmorgorov-complexity) challenges. This makes answers in the language a very rare occurrence. Other languages (such as [python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), [java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), [jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jelly), etc.) have their own tags because:

1. of their tips questions.

   - ;# cannot possibly have any tips, since any task that is possible in it is solvable in one and only one way.
2. parts of the language can be explored to make challenges about.

   - ;# has exactly two commands which have been explored *completely* in the few challenges done.

Furthermore, any more challenges could only possibly be "extensions" of the language, which has been shown in [:$](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122289/without-resetting), [+-#$%!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122343/make-a-interpreter) and [;#*:)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141055/make-a-interpreter).

Comment: Is answering a [tag:kolmorgorov-complexity] challenge with `;#` treated as `do not even attempt to golf the code`? If so it's not a language that answer anything?

Comment: fine it seems for polyglot